# Making field required due to selection of previous field

Tags: list-form, column

Is it possible to make a field required due to the selection of a previous field?

So, if I have a dropdown with options (a, b, c, d) and if the user selects "d" then notes are required, but if they choose any other no notes are required.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

I did it recently with jQuery, http://endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2916&start=10

This is what the code looks like in my scenario, something could be adapted for your use.

```
<script src="../../Resources/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/SPServices.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var text = $("input[title$='VenLookup']").val();
var text2 = $("select[title$='VenLookup'] :selected").text();
  if(text != "Other - Not Listed" || text2 != "Other - Not Listed")
   {
   $(".VendorDetails").hide();
   }
//For IE
$("input[title$='VenLookup']").change(function() {
  var inputTextVal = $("input[title$='VenLookup']").val();
    if(inputTextVal == "Other - Not Listed")
   {
      alert('Please fill out all the vendor fields that will appear on the form');
      $(".VendorDetails").show();
      $(".VendorLabel").append("<span class='ms-formvalidation'>&nbsp;*</span>");      
   }
   else {}
  });
// For Firefox
$("select[title$='VenLookup']").change(function() {
  var selectTextVal = $("select[title$='VenLookup'] :selected").text();
   if(selectTextVal == "Other - Not Listed")
   {
      alert('Please fill out all the vendor fields that will appear on the form');
      $(".VendorDetails").show();
      $(".VendorLabel").append("<span class='ms-formvalidation'>&nbsp;*</span>");   
   }
   else {}
});
function PreSaveAction() {
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Labs",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Lab_x0020_Location'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("input[title$='Lab']").val() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
   $("input[title='Lab ID']").val($(this).attr("ows_LabID"));
    }); //close each
  } //close complete
}); //close SPServices


var Intext = $("input[title$='VenLookup']").val();
var Seltext = $("select[title$='VenLookup'] :selected").text();
  if(Intext != "Other - Not Listed" || Seltext != "Other - Not Listed")
{
$("tr.VendorDetails input").each(function() {
    error = false;
    if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
     error = true;
    }
  });
  if (error) 
  {
   alert("Please fill out all required fields");  
    return false;
  } 
  else 
  {
    return true;
  }
}

} // close presave  
}); //end doc ready

</script>
```

Comment: Link now broken, can you please update? Also if you can give us a brief summary of the article that would be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Blast, Mark took the site from read ony to down.  I'll find my code and edit my post.

Comment: He hasn't moved the content somewhere else by any chance?

Comment: I thought he was keeping it as a read only archive since there was a lot of good content in the forums.

Comment: Found the code and edited my post if you were interested Alex.

Comment: @EricAlexander Could you please add some explanation for above code.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done OOB.  Use a custom form/infopath to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Either you develop your own custom field or you have modify your add and edit pages and add a bit of JavaScript/jquery to do this check.